# Adding a local cache server to an heroku dyno instance

Tags: django, caching, heroku, redis

Some context:

I have a django server hosted on Heroku, with Waitress to serve requests.
A single dyno has several threads that handle requests simultaneously.

The server among other things handles a torrent of events reported by numerous clients.
The events are written to a redis cache, to be later flushed to the DB.

My Goal:

I would like to optimize this by having the redis cache running on the same dyno that handles requests.
Each dyno will have it's own local cache server (which is shared by all worker threads).

Events will be pushed to the local cache (thus improving the response time). A periodic job (on each dyno) will then collect the events from the cache and flush them to the DB.

My problems:

- How do I add a redis cache to my dyno (not as an add-on). I understand it is possible but wasn't able to do it. ref: [Is redis on Heroku possible without an addon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929136/is-redis-on-heroku-possible-without-an-addon)
- A different cache server that I can add to my dyno would also be a good option.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No point in repeating the detailed answer given at [Is redis on Heroku possible without an addon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929136/is-redis-on-heroku-possible-without-an-addon)

It's possible, but there's no reason why a sane developer would go through this just to optimize something that is complete negligible and totally unscalable.

If you must have a local cache, try using [local memory caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) as your intermediate cache.

Comment: When using the local mem cache no cross-process caching is possible thus it us not suitable for my needs.

Comment: I agree that this isn't an orthodox solution, however I know for a fact that the performance improvement is not negligible.

Comment: @odedfos what's the speedup you've measured?

Comment: I attended an openhouse hosted by a large company which encountered the issue I described above. This was their solution to the problem which I was considering to apply myself. I'm afraid I have no numbers to back me up here...

Comment: @odedfos You have no numbers, yet you're absolutely sure you need this architectural change that will severely harm your ability to scale? Good luck my friend.